# Writing to csv makes column without being written

Tags: pandas, csv

I am trying to do math on a specific cell in a csv file with pandas, but whenever I try to do it, it adds a column on the left that looks like

```
, 
1,value,value
2,value,value
3,value,value
4,value,value
5,value,value
```

So if I run it multiple times it looks like

```
,
1,1,1,value,value
2,2,2,value,value
3,3,3,value,value
4,4,4,value,value
5,5,5,value,value
```

How do I make it not do this??

My code is: `add_e_trial = equations_reader.at[bank_indexer_addbalance, 1] = reciever_amount`

Comment: Is that one line of code enough for me to replicate your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you do a `df.to_csv`, include `index=False`. The left most column is the index of the dataset

```
df.to_csv(index=False)
```